# Using autocomplete with on the fly elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have autocomplete nested within a jquery that creates text elements on the fly. The autocomplete works properly on the `#url` text field on every text field I create, however, I cannot make it work on the price field.

It only works if `nextUrlId` is not increasing every time I press "Add" (without `nextUrlId++`). Because of this, I cannot autopopulate the price field upon selection from autocomplete.

This does not work:

```
    $('#AddUrl').click(function(){
        $('<p />').attr('id', 'urlParagraph' + nextUrlId)
                  .text("URL: ")
                  .appendTo('#inputBoxes');
        $( "#url"+nextUrlId ).catcomplete({
         delay: 0,
         minLength : 2,
         source: "searchsku.php",
           select: function(event, ui){
           $("#price"+nextUrlId).val(ui.item.price)}
    });
    NextUrlId++
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inputBoxes">
   <table border="1">
       <tr>
         <td><p id="nameParagraph">Name: <input type="text" id="name" /></p>    </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><p id="urlParagraph1">URL: <input type="text" id="url1" /></p> </td>
       </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML too? I can't quite tell what is going on from your post, maybe post some more information too?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you have two related fields for each URL. One with an autocomplete box, and one with a price. Depending on the autocomplete entry, the price box should change value. I haven't tested this, but I belive something like this should work well. Instead of keeping track of ID's, you're just looking at the sibling element of the autocomplete field. Many ways of doing this, two examples below, in preferred order.

```
<div id="inputBoxes">
  <p class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" class="autocompleter" name="autocompleter[]">
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price">
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="addURL">
</div>
```

### Solution 1

```
$(".inputbox").find(".autocompleter").catcomplete({
  delay: 0,
  minLength : 2,
  source: "searchsku.php",
  select: function(event, ui){
    $(this).siblings(".price").val(ui.item.price);
  }
});
```

```
$("#addURL").bind("click",function(){
  var last = $(".inputbox").last();
  var newItem = last.clone()
  newItem.insertAfter(last);
  newItem.find(".autocompleter").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength : 2,
    source: "searchsku.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
      $(this).siblings(".price").val(ui.item.price);
    }
  });
});
```

### Solution 2

If you would prefer a fixed relation between the autocomplete field and the price fields within each paragraph, I'd do something like this.

```
<div id="inputBoxes">
  <p class="inputbox">
    <input type="text" rel="1" class="autocompleter" name="autocompleter[]">
    <input type="text" rel="1" name="price[]" class="price">
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="addURL">
</div>
```

```
$(".inputbox").find(".autocompleter").catcomplete({
  delay: 0,
  minLength : 2,
  source: "searchsku.php",
  select: function(event, ui){
    $('.price[rel="'+$(this).attr("rel")+'"]').val(ui.item.price);
  }
});
```

```
$("#addURL").bind("click",function(){
  var last = $(".inputbox").last();
  var newItem = last.clone()
  newItem.insertAfter(last);
  var lastRel = last.find(".autocompleter").attr("rel");
  newItem.find(".autocompleter").attr("rel",lastRel+1);
  newItem.find(".price").attr("rel",lastRel+1);

  newItem.find(".autocompleter").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength : 2,
    source: "searchsku.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
      $('.price[rel="'+$(this).attr("rel")+'"]').val(ui.item.price);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hmm, doesnt seem to work. Im also afraid that once I click to create a new element, rediting the original text field will not bring about a change on the price, because the last and new have changed by then.. Was hoping for a more elegant, by ID approach. But for some reason, I cant get the nested $ object to accept a dynamic variable attached to the object name. is this a limitation of jquery?

Comment: True, you also need to initialize an autocompleter for the old field.
Is the HTML structure similar to what you're using?

I'd still recommend looking at the sibling; but you could always add a connection between the autocompleter and the pricefield. But if, so why not add the id to the containing paragraph? I'll test it in a html page and edit in this as two separate solutions.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean old field? the original field has a separate autocompleter (not included in the text above).

Comment: Sorry. With the old field, I mean the original field. I did not add an autocompleter to that. If you have one since before it should work fine, since when cloning the elements, an automcompleter is added to each new element. 

Naturally, you could do this with ID's too if you really prefer. But you would need to use more code for it.

I made some changes above, tested the first one with the common autocompleter plugin. Second is just a prototype for reference, so it might contain some minor typos.